# Display full session storage in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I want to see session storage in internet explorer's console. 
The property is a large string value (json string) which is build after concatenating multiple session data.
Unfortunately, sessionStorage.property or sessionStorage.getItem("property") is not displaying full data. 
For example, if the json is large (have a large string data), it is displaying first few , maybe around 100, characters. So only partial json is available for display. 
Apologies for asking pity question, but I was unable to find this on Google search.
Edit: It will be very beneficial, if I can get data in string format. My main motive is to get the json and run it in rest client, so we can test it against various unpublished services.

Comment: Parse the JSON and log the object instead?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to save the data into sessionStorage?

Answer (score 2):

How about parsing it first and then throwing it to console?

```
var output = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
console.log(output);
```

Using localStorage or sessionStorage, I use JSON.stringify to set the data.

```
sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
```

The to get the data, I use JSON.parse:

```
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
```

This way I don't have to worry about the type of data (string, int, object). The downside is that, when looking at the data thru a browser, the data is in a string format and is double quoted.

Comment: But this way, we wont be getting string type data. I simply want complete json in string format. This is not a problem in chrome though.

Comment: You said you couldn't display it. So, I was hoping that by converting the string to an object you could then console.log it to see the data. If you need the exact string, try console.log(sessionStorage.getItem(key)).

Comment: Already tried that, getting half string only or in other words partial json string

Comment: Just open the Console and type it in: sessionStorage.getItem("property") . I just tested a long string in IE 11 and it works. You do have to scroll it to the right.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that already. It starts with double quotes, shows around quarter of the total string, and then it ends with double quotes.
I will try to get length of that full string from chrome.

I wish I could show you the code to save json data to storage, but I am restricted not only by policies but also by the environment. I am not UI developer and I dont have the code except source that I can extract from browser itself...

Comment: Looks like the Json is pretty large. Its showing upto 1024 characters and not after that. total json string length is 4256

Comment: That sounds like it's a built in limitation to IE Developer Tools. Have you tried methods other that .log(), such as .debug()? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772183.aspx Can you just switch to the Chrome browser?

Comment: Apologies for delay. I tried using debug but result is same. It looks like the string above 1024 chars are trimmed. Is it somehow possible to store sessionstorage value to file from console than to display it.
It must be storing whole json correctly else site can never function as expected in ie. So I believe if we can change any console setting or display it somewhere else other than console will resolve the problem, only if its possible in ie

Comment: You can send the value thru a .ajax (jQuery) call to a server side controller/method. You'd have to write all that code, but it should give you the value server side; PHP for example. Then you could echo it to the screen, save it to a file or echo the json_decoded() value.

Comment: While I am no good at any web development, nor I have privileges to modify any code, json parsing after stringify leads to me closest format from which I can get my data for debugging purposes. Thanks for your valuable help :)